# Find number of lines in PPT titles

Tags: c#, powerpoint, openxml-sdk

I can't seem to find the number of forced newlines in PowerPoint slide titles.

It is not a newline character of any kind, and it is not considered a paragraph ending. According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/792e043f-63bd-4cfb-8715-5d2fa58b32ea/in-powerpoint-find-and-replace-return-in-slide-title?forum=isvvba), it is a vertical tab, CHR(11). But that doesn't work either (see below).

Trying to get the character gives no result. I have a title like this in a pptx file:

A

B

(A[enter]B)

.substring(0) returns A

.substring(1) returns B

I have not tried .substring(0.5), but I'm close to that point.

Here is what is supposed to work, but it doesn't, it just returns 1.

```
int rowCount = titleText.Length-titleText.Replace(((char)11).ToString(),"").Length+1;
```

I'm using Office Open XML SDK 2.5.
Thanks!

EDIT:

Similar code in PowerPoint VBA works perfectly well.

EDIT2:

Maybe getting paragraph texts is what destroys the vertical tab? Adding counters to the loops gives 1 each.

```
                foreach (var paragraph in shape.TextBody.Descendants<A.Paragraph>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in paragraph.Descendants<A.Text>())
                    {
                        shapeText += text.Text;
                    }
                }
                returnText.Append(analyzeTitleText(shapeText));
```

private static string analyzeTitleText(string titleText)

```
int rowCount = titleText.Length-titleText.Replace(((char)11).ToString(),"").Length+1;
```

etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newlines are stored as [`Break`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/documentformat.openxml.drawing.break%28v=office.14%29.aspx) elements so you need to count the number of Breaks in your title elements.

I created an example slide with a title of `A[enter]b[enter]` and extracted the XML. The relevant part of the slide1.xml file looks like this:

```
<a:p>
    <a:r>
        <a:rPr lang="en-GB" smtClean="0" />
        <a:t>A</a:t>
    </a:r>
    <a:br>
        <a:rPr lang="en-GB" smtClean="0" />
    </a:br>
    <a:r>
        <a:rPr lang="en-GB" smtClean="0" />
        <a:t>b</a:t>
    </a:r>
    <a:br>
        <a:rPr lang="en-GB" smtClean="0" />
    </a:br>
    <a:endParaRPr lang="en-GB" />
</a:p>
```

Note the `<a:br>` elements - these are the new lines.

Adapting the example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc850843.aspx) which shows how to get the title elements, the following will output the number of new lines in the title on each of your slides (note that `IsTitleSlide` is defined in that MSDN article, I haven't copied that code here as getting the title isn't your issue):

```
using (PresentationDocument presentationDocument = PresentationDocument.Open(filepath, false))
{
    PresentationPart presentationPart = presentationDocument.PresentationPart;

    if (presentationPart != null && presentationPart.Presentation != null)
    {
        Presentation presentation = presentationPart.Presentation;

        if (presentation.SlideIdList != null)
        {
            foreach (var slideId in presentation.SlideIdList.Elements<SlideId>())
            {
                SlidePart slidePart = presentationPart.GetPartById(slideId.RelationshipId) as SlidePart;

                var shapes = slidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation.Shape>().Where(IsTitleShape);

                int newLines = shapes.SelectMany(s => s.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Break>()).Count();
                Console.WriteLine("Slide {0} has {1} new lines", slidePart.Uri, newLines);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the above example slide that code returns:

> Slide /ppt/slides/slide1.xml has 2 new lines

Comment: Thank you very much! Perfect. Next time I'll take a peek at the generated code, I feel stupid for not doing it in the first place. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries @vacip. The [Open XML SDK Productivity Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30425&751be11f-ede8-5a0c-058c-2ee190a24fa6=True) is always worth using too if you don't already use it. Good luck!